# Timezone from address or zipcode - Here API

Tags: here-api

I am trying to query timezone based on address or zipcode in HereMaps API. If any one knows can you please share the information.

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is the example data and expected output? Where is your effort so far? Please edit your question accordingly. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Geocoding REST API can provide you timezone, when specifying locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone

[Exemple of Reverse Geocoding request](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=XXXXX&app_code=YYYYYY&prox=LAT,LNG&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone)

and extract of result:

[image]